# Dynamically created bootstrap buttons lose space padding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the a bootstrap button bar using the `well` class repeated twice in my code: one created using HTML code and another using dynamic javascript.

When I use HTML, the bootstrap works fine.

Whan I use javascript to create it, the buttons lose its padding.

The result I expect is the same in both code.

Why does the dynamic created one does not respect the original horizontal spacing that the HTML created one has ?

Does anyone can help me with that.

```
Original code:

<div class="well">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Button 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Button 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Button 3</button>
    <small class="pull-right">Right Text</small>
</div>


<div id="myMenu">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var upperWell = $("<div class='well clearfix'>");

        $('#myMenu').append(upperWell);

        var createButton = $("<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'>Button1</button>");

        var updateButton = $("<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'>Button 2</button>");

        var exportButton = $("<button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs'>Button 3</button>");

        $(upperWell).append(createButton);
        $(upperWell).append(updateButton);
        $(upperWell).append(exportButton);

    });

</script>
```

The JsFiddle is here:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P7pTL/2/)

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The static buttons have whitespace between them, the appended buttons don't. You can add a space between each button...

```
$(upperWell).append(createButton).append(" ");
$(upperWell).append(updateButton).append(" ");
$(upperWell).append(exportButton);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buXku/)

Or you can add a space after each button after they're appended...

```
$(upperWell).append(createButton);
$(upperWell).append(updateButton);
$(upperWell).append(exportButton);

$("#myMenu button").after(" ");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B4Rp5/)

Comment: Sorry, I can´t see the whitespaces between the original buttons in the HTML code... Where is comes from ?

Comment: @Mendez Notice how your buttons are on separate lines?  The new lines (and tabs) count as white space.

Comment: There is a new line and some spaces/tabs between each button in the mark up.

Comment: But am I not adding the same new line as whitespacing when creating dynamically ? If I look at the browser code, they are exactly the same...

Comment: They might show up the same when inspecting the DOM. In Chrome, right-click on the div surrounding the dynamically generated buttons and edit as HTML to see the actual generated HTML. You'll see there's nothing between the buttons.

Comment: The difference for me was dynamically generated HTML using `<li><a...</li>` that had no whitespace but the raw HTML that this code was being inserted into has whitespace before from code indenting. By adding a space before or after `li`s in JS it was solved.

Answer (score 3):

When we applied a `display: inline-block;` property to any element, there showing a small gap between two elements.

Refer this link http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

But if there is no space between elements (like your buttons created by javascript), the space will not shown.

In your code, When buttons are created by javascript, it appedns in HTML code without any spacing.

Original code:

`<div class="well">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Button 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Button 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Button 3</button>
    <small class="pull-right">Right Text</small>
</div>`

Dynamically generated code:

`<div class="well clearfix"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Button1</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Button 2</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Button 3</button></div>`

To overcome the above problem you can use the following code

`#myMenu button {
   margin-right: 4px;
}`